# Naming variable using _n_, a column for each iteration of a datastep

Tags: sas

I need to declare a variable for each iteration of a datastep (for each *n*), but when I run the code, SAS will output only the last one variable declared, the greatest *n*.

It seems stupid declaring a variable for each row, but I need to achieve this result, I'm working on a dataset created by a proc freq, and I need a column for each group (each row of the dataset).

The result will be in a macro, so it has to be completely flexible.

```
proc freq data=&data noprint ;
table &group / out=frgroup;
run;

data group1;
set group (keep=&group count ) end=eof;
call symput('gr', _n_);
*REQUESTED code will go here;
run;
```

I tried these:

```
var&gr.=.;
call missing(var&gr.);
```

and a lot of other statement, but none worked.
Always the same result, the ds includes only var&gr where &gr is the maximum *n*.

It seems that the PDV is overwriting the new variable each iteration, but the name is different.
Please, include the result in a single datastep, or, at least, let the code take less time as possible.

Any idea on how can I achieve the requested result?

Thanks.

Comment: please, don't use proc transpose because I need 3 columns for each row, right_&gr sep_&gr left_&gr, this will be fed by some data and then an ods output.

Comment: also, I can fix this using a call execute, but if possible I'm searching for a solution that doesn't require that time, a simple variable declaration would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro variables don't work like you think they do. Any macro variable reference is resolved at compile time, so your `call symput` is changing the value of the macro variable after all the references have been resolved. The reason you are getting results where the &gr is the maximum *n* is because that is what &gr was as a result of the last time you ran the code.

If you know you can determine the maximum `_n_`, you can put the max value into a macro variable and declare an array like so:

Find max `_n_` and assign value to `maxn`:

```
data _null_;
  set have end=eof;
  if eof then call symput('maxn',_n_);
run;
```

Create variables:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array var (&maxn);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this completely changed my vision about macro programming. Macro variables are solved only at the end of the processing.
But, now, is it impossible to use, into a dataset, a macro variable defined into the same datastep?

Comment: You _can_ actually get the value of a macro variable in the same data step using the `symget()` function or the `resolve()` function, but those are limited in its usefulness as they are only valid in expressions and can't really be used like macro variable references can.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like `proc transpose` (if you need 3 columns you can always use it once for every column and then put together the outputs) what you ask can be done with arrays.

First thing you need to determine the number of groups (i.e. rows) in the input dataset and then define an array with dimension equal to that number.

Then the i-th element of your array can be recalled using `_n_` as index.
In the following code `&gr.` contains the number of groups:

```
data group1;
    set group;
    array arr_counts(&gr.) var1-var&gr.;
    arr_counts(_n_)= count;
run;
```

In SAS there're several methods to determine the number of obs in a dataset, my favorite is the following: (doesn't work with views)

```
data _null_;
    if 0 then set group nobs=n;
    call symputx('gr',n);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Using the function nobs= seems to be a great solution, but now, is there a way to use that 'a' as argument for the length of an array? something like array variables[n] $ var: ?